# How to print distinct error with count in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, printf

I have a huge file from where I have to fetch distinct error for current date and get its count. I have written below command but last line is not working as expected.

The first two line is filtering the error message based on current date and ERROR keyword. What I am expecting from third line is to print the error Message from `finalfile.txt` and gets it count.
I am getting output as 1 in final1.txt file. I am expecting as below

```
ErrorMessageEventPersister 7(first column is error message and second is its count  in finalfile.txt)

grep "$(date +"%y-%m-%d")" /home/dev/Medha/artim-session.log > newfile.txt

grep  "ERROR" /home/dev/Medha/newfile.txt > finalfile.txt

printf '%s' "ErrorMessageEventPersister" /home/dev/Medha/finalfile.txt | grep -c  "ErrorMessageEventPersister" > final1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep "$(date +"%y-%m-%d")" /home/dev/Medha/artim-session.log | grep ERROR | grep -o ErrorMessageEventPersister | uniq -c > final1.txt
```

I prefer `cut` column of interest (e.g.: 4th) and print top 10 errors:

```
grep "$(date +"%y-%m-%d")" my.log | grep ERROR | cut -d" " -f 4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

check `man grep`, `man wc`, `man cut`, `man sort` and `man uniq`